# How can I perform a dictionary lookup based on elements in a list/set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, lookup

Say I have a list of values like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and I generated some dictionary key based on these values so if I had another list [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] it would generate the same key to be able to perform the dictionary lookup on the same value.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
key_1 = generate_key(a)

b = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
key_2 = generate_key(b)

dict = {...}
assert dict[key_1] == dict[key_2]
assert key_1 == key_2
```

Are there any algorithms that could generate the same key for the same values of a list/set?
The list/set can contain strings and there are no duplicates involved.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) since there are no duplicates:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

key_1 = frozenset(a)
key_2 = frozenset(b)

key_1 == key_2
# True
hash(key_1) == hash(key_2)
# True
```

If there were duplicates and the number of occurrences mattered, you could use a [`sorted`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/sorted.html) [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple):

```
key_1 = tuple(sorted(a))
key_2 = tuple(sorted(b))
```

Both approaches assume all the values inside the lists/sets are themselves hashable. Otherwise, you would need some sort of recursive approach.

Comment: Got me to learn about both frozenset and hash. And the importance of immutability (hence frozenset not set) for hashing. Thanks!